# NSCalendar.dateFromComponents returns wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to store and retrieve a specific time in my app's user defaults (since it's recurring events date has no relevance and is ignored), but I'm having this bizarre issue where the hour is correct but the minutes and seconds are not

Here's my code

```
var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
var flags: NSCalendarUnit = .MinuteCalendarUnit | .HourCalendarUnit | .SecondCalendarUnit
var components = calendar?.components(flags, fromDate: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("breakfastTime") as NSDate!)
let test = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components!) as NSDate!
NSLog("Components: %@", components!)
NSLog("Date 1: %@", NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("breakfastTime") as NSDate)
NSLog("Date 3: %@", test!)
```

Components correctly outputs the time, as such

```
Components: <NSDateComponents: 0x17414a7c0>
Hour: 8
Minute: 30
Second: 0
```

And the date is correctly retrieved from the user defaults

```
Date 1: 2015-01-28 07:30:00 +0000
(It's 7 rather than 8 but it makes sense, since it's stored at UTC)
```

However, this happens when using dateFromComponents

```
Date 3: 0001-01-01 07:40:04 +0000
```

I don't even understand where the 40 and 04 come from

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how that has anything to do with it (it was my understanding that timezones only shift hours) but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve your problem by setting the timezone correctly.
For example :

```
calendar?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!
```